# Install docker compose v2 on aws linux 2

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have docker installed on my r5.2xlarge running aws linux 2. I'm trying to install `docker compose` v2 to no avail.

Following the docker linux [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/):

> Set up the respository

What distro do I select for this? I tried using CentOS, but the `sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin` step failed for me with

```
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'docker-ce-stable':
  - Status code: 404 for https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/2023.2.20230920/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 3.163.24.55)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'docker-ce-stable': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Ignoring repositories: docker-ce-stable
Last metadata expiration check: 2:45:33 ago on Sun Oct  1 22:27:32 2023.
No match for argument: docker-ce
No match for argument: docker-ce-cli
No match for argument: containerd.io
No match for argument: docker-buildx-plugin
No match for argument: docker-compose-plugin
Error: Unable to find a match: docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

If I install through `yum` normally and then continue with `sudo yum install docker-compose-plugin`, I get

```
Last metadata expiration check: 2:53:00 ago on Sun Oct  1 22:27:32 2023.
No match for argument: docker-compose-plugin
Error: Unable to find a match: docker-compose-plugin
```

Comment: Amazon Linux diverged from CentOS long ago. https://gist.github.com/npearce/6f3c7826c7499587f00957fee62f8ee9 may be helpful.

Comment: That installs docker compose v1 afaict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instruction in the "[Install plugin manually](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/#install-the-plugin-manually)" section worked for me. Before I was installing to the `ec2-user` user and testing via `sudo docker compose version` - I had to follow the instructions for installing to all users.